# How to add save() method generically to classes that have a DataContract?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a class with `DataContract` that can be saved to a file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace Test
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public float Value;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.Value = 2.3F;

            data.Save(@"D:\result.txt");
        }

        public void Save(string path)
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Data));

            serializer.WriteObject(stream, this);
        }
    }
}
```

I have other classes with `[DataContract]` that I also want to save. I do not want to repeat the code in every class. **How can I add the `Save()` method to all classes that have a `[DataContract]`?**

Ideally, this would work in an extension method with serializer as parameter, but what should the type `???` be?

```
public static class SaveExtension
{
    public static void Save(this ??? serializable, string path, DataContractSerializer serializer)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        serializer.WriteObject(stream, serializable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your extension method generic:

```
    public void Save<T>(this T obj, string path)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

        serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
    }
```

Then it will work for *any* type.

Note that you can create the serializer in the save method since it is passed the type at runtime.

Comment: I don't want this to work for *any* type. I don't want to have code completion suggest a `Save()` method on every type, even if it doesn't make sense to call it (for lack of `[DataContract]`). If I create the serializer in the method, I'm stuck with that serializer. If it was passed to the method, I could pass a different one if necessary. At least that was the motivation behind the Serializer parameter.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the extension methods are added to types, but those types that make sense to be passed to `WriteObject()` are not easily identifiable with generics. If the Serializers were generically typed, this would be easier, but they aren't. How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you explain how generic serializer would help? They're _basically_ generic since you pass in the type that you want to serialize.  To answer the other question you would have to create a base type or interface that all of your data types inherit/implement in order to add a generic constraint.  There's no way to constrain the generic type at compile-time based on attributes.  You could do it at run-time but not at compile-time.

Comment: A generic Serializer would not take `Object` as a type of the object to be written, but its generic type. With a known type, the extension method could be added only to this type. A generic serializer would also be able to have a `ReadObject()` that returns its type, but that's not part of this question...

Comment: OK I see.  Not sure how it helps in this case but I see your point.